# Как установить плагин cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Источник](http://helpexe.ru/programmirovanie/kak-zashifrovat-zashhitit-ishodnyj-kod)  Установите плагин, используя следующую команду в вашем терминале (как только вы окажетесь в папке вашего проекта):  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Я пишу в терминале  Android Studio

```
-cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file
```

а мне в ответ

```
C:\APK\name_test>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file
"cordova" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем, я прошёл этот путь )

Сначала устанавливаешь NodeJS отсюда https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Проверяешь установку, в терминале:
node - v

Потом открываешь терминал NodeJS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из других термиалов установка почему-то не запускается. Вводишь

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Процесс пошёл. Потом проверяешь

```
cordova -v
```

Нарыл всё на англоязычном stackoverflow, отовсюду понемногу

Comment: спасибо........